# every class of application installing individually in the phone.

Tags: android

I developed an android application with no errors. It is installed in my phone and functioning perfectly but the only problem is, when I'm installing the application. It is installing all the classes in application individually and along with it my main application.

So, how should I prevent all the classes installing individually. please help me.

Comment: Can't really tell what you're asking here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that your AndroidManifest.xml has multiples of this:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Which is causing multiple icons to be showed for each `Activity`
Find all the "extra" ones and delete them. This used to be an issue with the ADT plugin a while back (every time you made a new `Activity` via the wizard, it would auto add it with launcher attributes), you seem to be on an older version. You should update it.

Comment: where shud i keep it n remove all da extra once

Comment: The extra `intent-filters` aren't needed so you don't keep them. You only need it for your **main** `Activity`. I can't tell what your main Activity is, since that's up to *you* to decide.